# Как анимируется цвет?

Tags: css3, svg, transition, цвета, интерполяция

Как интерполируется цвет при анимации? Что происходит, если указанная кривая безье выходит на пределы интерполируемого отрезка?

Т. е. есть

```
y = transitionTimintFunction(t) // некое текущее значение
с0 = rgb(255, 0, 0)             // начальный цвет
с1 = rgb(0, 0, 255)             // конечный цвет
```

как по ним посчитать функцию

```
c = color(c0, c1)(y)            // интерполированное значение цвета
```

И что с ней произойдёт, если внезапно окажется, что `y<0` или `y>1`?

[image: кривая безье]

```css
div {
  width: 10em;
  height: 10em;
  transition: background-color 3s cubic-bezier(0,2,.5,-2);
  background-color: red;
}

div:hover {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102465/discussion-on-question-by-qwertiy---).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Линейная интерполяция в целом совпала с ожиданиями:

Алгоритм интерполяция цвета - каждый канал интерполируется по отдельности.

```js
requestAnimationFrame(f);
let t = Date.now();
let elem = document.querySelector('.left2');
document.querySelector('.left1').classList.add('linear');

function f() {
  let dt = Date.now() - t;
  dt < 2e4 && requestAnimationFrame(f);
  dt /= 2e4;
  if (!elem) {
    
  }
  elem.style.left = 100*dt + '%';
  elem.style.borderRight = `10px solid rgb(${dt*255},0,${(1-dt)*255})`
}
```

```css
section {
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px dotted red;
}

div {
  height: 4em;
  width: 0;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: -5px;
}

.bezier {
  animation: 20s left cubic-bezier(0,2,.5,-2) forwards;
}

.linear {
  animation: 20s left linear forwards;
}

@keyframes left {
  0% { left: 0;border-right: 10px solid blue;}
  100% {left: 100%;border-right: 10px solid red;}
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="left1"></div>
</section>
<section>
  <div class="left2"></div>
</section>
```

Comment: Что-то рассинхрон, особенно при первом запуске, огромный: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4FeqK.png

Comment: @Qwertiy вроде пофиксил

Comment: Да, вроде похоже.